# UWP app definition

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal, definition

We're going to develop an UWP app and it'll be for Mobile and Desktop.
In our presentation, could we say our app is Universal, even not testing or deploying on Surface Hub, Holo Lens and Xbox?

Comment: That's a question you'll have to ask your legal department.

Comment: Without Quality Assurance done, you are going to have your company reputation hits rock bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to the first paragraph of [Official Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide):

> The UWP provides a guaranteed core API layer across devices. This means **you can create a single app package that can be installed onto a wide range of devices.**

But:

> Because your UWP app runs on a wide variety of devices with different form factors and input modalities, you want it to be tailored to each device and be able to unlock the unique capabilities of each device. **Devices add their own unique APIs to the guaranteed API layer.** You can write code to access those unique APIs conditionally so that your app lights up features specific to one type of device while presenting a different experience on other devices.

So it is Universal on condition that you are not triggering some platform specific API Codes. And for UI, UWP is also using adaptive UI to let the app fit for different screen size.

Comment: Indeed without platform specific code you could say it's in theory possible to run app on HoloLens or Xbox, until you actually run it on those devices then can say with certainty - if an app has a good "big screen" experience that lends itself well to HoloLens and Xbox

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use the world universal, because by definition all Windows 10 apps, which do not use some specific APIs which would restrict them to only one device family are universal.

Back in the days of Windows 8.1, the apps which were targeting Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 were **also called "Universal".**

The point is, that the package, which you deploy is the **same on both Windows 10 on PCs and on Windows 10 Mobile**.

Usually these two SKUs are the primary targets of Windows 10 developers and only a smaller number of developers can test on Xbox One and even smaller on Surface Hub and HoloLens.

When publishing to Windows Store, you can **restrict your package only to the device families you have tested on**. For most cases however, your app should work well on Surface Hub, HoloLens and Xbox even without testing (even though the user input will not be optimized and it might not work as intuitively as expected).